# Plot a vector field over a line

Tags: plotting, vector, mesh

This seemingly simple problem is giving me some trouble. I need to plot a vector field on a line, and for that I'm following what I found [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VectorPlot.html). I try to create a mesh that contains two points and just plot vectors on it:

```
\[ScriptCapitalD] = MeshRegion[{{0, 1}, {1, 1}}, Line[{1, 2}]];
VectorPlot[{Sin[x], Cos[y]}, {x, y} \[Element] \[ScriptCapitalD]]
```

But I get the following error:

```
VectorPlot::idomdim:  does not have a valid dimension as a plotting domain. >>
```

What's wrong with this approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion the easy way to plot vectors over 1D curve is to used `VectorPoints` option:

```
points = Table[{i, 1}, {i, 0, 1, .1}];
VectorPlot[{Sin[x], Cos[y]}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, -1, 2}, 
 VectorPoints -> points, VectorScale -> {0.1, .2}, 
 Epilog -> Point[points]]
```

Comment: I like your solution. Is there a way to have the tail of the vectors at the points?

Comment: Yes you can add 'VectorStyle->"LeftArrow'

Answer (score 5):

I don't know how to make this with `RegionFunction`s but you could show the vectors along the `Line[{{0, 1}, {1, 1}}]` like this:

```
VectorPlot[{Sin[x], Cos[y]}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0.5, 1.5},
 AspectRatio -> 1/5,
 FrameTicks -> {True, {0.95, 1, 1.05}, False, False},
 GridLines -> {None, {1}},
 GridLinesStyle -> {Blue, Dashed},
 PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0.95, 1.05}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Well, here's a way that works when the number of seconds since Jan. 1, 1970 is odd (that is, it crashes the kernel every other time I execute it):

```
reg = MeshRegion[{{0, 1}, {1, 1.001}}, Line[{1, 2}]];
points = MeshCoordinates@ DiscretizeRegion[reg, MaxCellMeasure -> {"Length" -> 0.1}];
vf = Table[{p, {Sin[x], Cos[y]} /. Thread[{x, y} -> p]}, {p, points}];
ListVectorPlot[vf, VectorPoints -> All, 
 Frame -> {{False, False}, {True, False}}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Maybe someone will find a way that doesn't randomly stumble over a bug.

A manual construction that doesn't crash:

```
vfvec[{p_, v_}, scale_: 1] := Arrow[{p, p + scale*v}];
Graphics[{Arrowheads[0.03], vfvec[#, 0.1]} & /@ vf,
 Frame -> {{False, False}, {True, False}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you want centered arrows like `VectorPlot`, then change `vfvec` to

```
vfvec[{p_, v_}, scale_: 1] := Arrow[{p - scale*v/2, p + scale*v/2}];
```