# Plotting vector field on the real line

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, vector

I am trying to plot the vector field of 
`x'=x-x^3`
On the real line, and cannot seem to tweak the two dimensional examples I have found.

Bonus points if I can also plot the graph of `f(x)=x-x^3` and then input the direction vectors along the x axis underneath the graph, but not necessary.

edit: Here is what I have been trying, found here:
[Plot a vector field over a line](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/104203/plot-a-vector-field-over-a-line?rq=1)

```
points = Table[{i, 1}, {i, 0, 1, .1}];
VectorPlot[{x - x^3, 0}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -1, 1}, 



VectorPoints -> points, VectorScale -> {4, .1}, 

 Epilog -> Point[points]]
```

but it gives me a pretty lame plot with weird scaling. Changing the values of the parameters doesn't seem to do much, possibly because i copied this from a previous post and dont really know what each command is doing.

Modified Felix's answer to get the following:

```
f[x_] := x - x^3;

fp[x_] := Evaluate[D[f[x], x]];

arrowLength = 0.1;

xmin = -5;

xmax = 5;

Show[Plot[f[x], {x, xmin, xmax}], 

 Show[Table[



Graphics[Arrow[{{x, 0}, {x + Sign[f[x]], 0}}]], {x, xmin, 
xmax, (xmax - xmin)/10}]]]
```

Which is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks Felix

Comment: Does this work or you want the Phase Line StreamPlot[{1, x - x^3}, {y, -5, 5}, {x, -5, 5}]?

Comment: @Moo Hm im not sure what's going on there, it is also giving vectors in the wrong direction; they should be negative for large x. I am looking for something exactly like this:  http://www.scielo.cl/fbpe/img/rchnat/v77n4/FIG2pag715.jpg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this?

```
f[x_] := x - x^3;
fp[x_] := Evaluate[D[f[x], x]];
arrowLength = 0.1;
xmin = 0;
xmax = 1;
Show[Plot[f[x], {x, xmin, xmax}], 
 Show[Table[
   Graphics[
    Arrow[{{x, f[x]}, {x + arrowLength Cos[ArcTan[fp[x]]], 
       f[x] + arrowLength Sin[ArcTan[fp[x]]]}}]], {x, xmin, 
    xmax, (xmax - xmin)/10}]]]
```

[image]

The issue with your original approach is that you are not looking for a vector field. A vector field assigns a vector to every point in real space. However, you want to assign vectors only to those points where $y=f(x)$. This is done by plotting arrows, not vector fields.

The code above first produces a stack (list) of arrows at 10 points between `xmin` and `xmax`. The arrows start at the function graph points $(x,f(x))$ and point in the direction defined by the derivative. The length is set to `0.1`. All arrows are then drawn in one graphics using `Show`. The outer-most `Show` then adds a plot of the actual function to that graphics.

**Update:**

This gives you the arrows only at the positions of the root, indicating if the function has a positive or negative derivative at the root as shown in your example.

```
f[x_] := x - x^3;
fp[x_] := Evaluate[D[f[x], x]];
roots = x /. Solve[f[x] == 0, x];
arrowLength = 0.1;
xmin = -0.2;
xmax = 1.2;
drawRootArrow[x_, sgn_, al_] := 
  Show[Graphics[
    Arrow[{{x - al (1 - sgn)/2, 0}, {x - al (1 + sgn)/2, 0}}]], 
   Graphics[
    Arrow[{{x + al (1 - sgn)/2, 0}, {x + al (1 + sgn)/2, 0}}]]];
Show[Plot[f[x], {x, xmin, xmax}], 
 Show[Table[drawRootArrow[x, Sign[fp[x]], arrowLength], {x, roots}]]]
```

[image]

Comment: hmmm not quite, although I may be able to tweak it a little. I was hoping to have the arrows you have lying on the x axis, pointing forward whenever $f$ is positive above them, and backwards whenever $f$ is negative (which would be below them).

Comment: ah! I found a picture: http://www.scielo.cl/fbpe/img/rchnat/v77n4/FIG2pag715.jpg

Comment: So you want to draw the arrows only at the roots of `f`?

Comment: Yes I guess i only need vectors in between the roots of $f$

Comment: I modified your code to get exactly what I wanted (put into question). Thanks!